# Kernels of surjections from a vector bundle to a reflexive sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Reflexive sheaves on a regular quasi-projective variety can be characterized by the following property that they are the kernel of a surjection from a vector bundle to a torsion-free sheaf. I wonder what the class of reflexive sheaves that are kernel of a surjection from a vector bundle to a reflexive sheaf consists of? They are clearly reflexive but can any reflexive sheaf written in that form? Or under what conditions every reflexive sheaf is a kernel of a surjection from a vector bundle to another reflexive sheaf? Is there any other way to characterize these specific reflexive sheaves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ambient variety is smooth, the locus of points where a reflexive sheaf is not locally free has codimension at least 3. And for a sheaf which is a kernel of a surjection from locally free to reflexive, this sheaf has codimension at least 4. So, the classes are different.

In general, one can consider so-called **locally $m$-syzygy sheaves** --- these are sheaves $F$ for which there is a resolution
$$
0 \to F \to E_1 \to E_2 \to \dots \to E_m
$$
(not necessarily exact in the rightmost term) with $E_i$ locally free. For $m = 1$ these are torsion-free sheaves, for $m = 2$ reflexive, and for $m = 3$ your class.

Comment: Is there a reference that proves this? Is this still true of the base field is not algebraically closed?

Comment: The case $m=1$ (torsion-free) is Tag [0AUU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUU), and then $m=2$ follows from that and Tag [0AV2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AV2), and $m=3$ is your class by definition.

Comment: I meant is the following statement true? "A reflexive sheaf is in my class iff it is a vector bundle on the complement of a closed subvariety of codimension 4"

Comment: Ah, can't you just prove that the same way as Tag [03BN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B3N)? I think the point is that when you localise to a point of codimension $\leq 3$, you get a maximal Cohen–Macaulay module (see Tag [00NF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NF)), which is free by Tag [00NT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NT).

Comment: I learnt this stuff from the book of Okonek-Schneider-Spindler.

Comment: As an answer to the question I asked above. The converse is not true i.e. if a reflexive sheaf  is a vector bundle on the complement of a codimension 4 subvariety, it doesn't need to be locally 3-syzygy sheaf. I figured this out through an unexpected contradiction, there might be an easier way of showing it.